# How to draw a kernel density plot using Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a set of timestamps (each corresponding to a student submission), and I wanted to take a look at them graphically. I know `criterion` uses a KDE and makes a nice plot, and it looks like it depends on the `statistics` package, which provides a `kde` function, but I couldn't trace through the code of `criterion` to see how it's being used.

Ideally, and answer would at least be a snippet of code that produces a picture. An explanation of what `criterion` does in this case would also be welcome.

Comment: Does the kde example in the `statistics` examples folder https://github.com/bos/statistics/tree/master/examples/kde do what you want? I think it's basically just the criterion usage.